# An adjustable shelf of long lengths is used to take various sizes of packs

Tags: word-usage

An adjustable shelf of long lengths is used to take various sizes of packs.
Is this sentence correct?

Refence:grage 11 English textbook(Burma)

Comment: Why are you asking a new question that's nearly identical to the first?

Comment: I can see that you still haven't taken the tour of this site.  You probably won't get satisfying results until you understand how to use the site and what is appropriate and not appropriate question-asking protocol.  It's really worth it to take a few minutes and take the tour: http://english.stackexchange.com/tour